# how to check if a value exists in a column in sqlite 3 python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-insert

I have a table (server_ preference) which has these headers:
guild_id - int
mod_channel_role_id - int
report_channel_id  - int
i want to check if guild_id exist in the guild id column if it does not i want to insert to the table new staff
i have tried many things and haven’t found any thing that worked this was my last attempt

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("server_preference.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    for guild in client.guilds:
        c.execute("""IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT guild_id FROM server_preference WHERE guild_id = ?)
                     BEGIN
                     INSERT INTO server_preference (guild_id) VALUES (:guild_id)
                     END""", guild.id)
        conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

and I got this error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "IF": syntax error

Comment: SQLite flavor sql syntax is documented at https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html ... Nowhere will you find a command starting with IF. You can't just throw random stuff at it and hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want duplicate  `guild_id`s in your table, then you should have the database enforce uniqueness with a unique constraint or index (they are pretty much equivalent).

So, start with:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_server_preference_guild_id ON server_preference(guild_id);
```

Then, if you run:

```
INSERT INTO server_preference (guild_id) VALUES (:guild_id);
```

You will get an error.  If you want to avoid an error, use an `ON CONFLICT` clause:

```
INSERT INTO server_preference (guild_id)
    VALUES (:guild_id)
    ON CONFLICT (guild_id) DO NOTHING;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this logic in a sngle statement by using the `insert ... select` syntax with a `not exists` condition:

```
insert into server_preference(guild_id)
select :guild_id
where not exists (select 1 from server_preference where guild_id = :guild_id)
```